# CNF form of the logical $exactly(2) x_{i}$

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, conjunctive-normal-form

Let's say, in order to linearize the product of the two binary variables the logical condition would be, z <=> (x and y), where x, y, and z are binary. The corresponding CNF form is as follows:

\begin{align*}
& z \iff x \wedge y \\
& \left(z \implies (x \wedge y)\right) \bigwedge \left((x \wedge y) \implies z\right) \\
& \left(\neg z \vee (x \wedge y)\right) \bigwedge \left(\neg(x \wedge y) \vee z\right) \\
& \left((\neg z \vee x) \wedge (\neg z \vee y)\right) \bigwedge \left((\neg x \vee \neg y) \vee z\right) \\
& (\neg z \vee x) \bigwedge (\neg z \vee y) \bigwedge (\neg x \vee \neg y \vee z) \\
& \left((1 - z) + x \ge 1\right) \bigwedge \left((1 - z) + y \ge 1\right) \bigwedge \left((1 - x) + (1 - y) + z \ge 1\right) \\
& (x \ge z) \bigwedge (y \ge z) \bigwedge (z \ge x + y - 1)
\end{align*}

and ***the last line is exactly what can be translated in the math form as three linear inequalities***. Now, my question is about the last line in the following expressions that I can translate from logic to math from original expression as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} = 2 \implies \delta = 1$, where $x_i$ and $\delta$ are binary:

$$ \text{exactly(2)}_i x_i \implies \delta = 1 $$
$$ \text{atleast(2)}_i x_i \land \text{atmost(2)}_i x_i \implies \delta = 1$$
$$ \lnot (\text{atleast(2)}_i x_i \land \text{atmost(2)}_i x_i) \lor \delta$$
$$ (\text{atmost(2-1)}_i x_i \lor \text{atleast(2+1)}_i x_i) \lor \delta$$
$$ (\text{atmost(1)}_i x_i \lor \text{atleast(3)}_i x_i) \lor \delta$$
$$ (\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \leq 1) \lor ((\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i} \geq 3) \lor \delta$$

Now, as it seems, the last line obviously needs the auxiliary binary variables to form a CNF in order to make indicators constraints. Would you please, is there any way to go deeper into the above logical form to making a CNF that can be directly converted to the math inequalities? (something like the last line of CNF form of product of the two binary variables is)?

Comment: To avoid additional variables, consider converting to CNF the proposition $$\left(\lor_{i<j} (x_i \land x_j\land \land_{k \notin \{i,j\}} \lnot x_k)\right) \implies \delta$$

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9549/mip-constraint-with-sum-of-decision-variables-having-certain-value-sum-i-1 https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that avoids introducing any additional variables, and the conjunctive normal form somewhat automatically yields $\binom{n}{2}$ linear constraints:
$$
\left(\bigvee_{i<j} \left(x_i \land x_j\land \bigwedge_{k \notin \{i,j\}} \lnot x_k\right)\right) \implies \delta \\
\lnot \left(\bigvee_{i<j} \left(x_i \land x_j\land \bigwedge_{k \notin \{i,j\}} \lnot x_k\right)\right) \lor \delta \\
\left(\bigwedge_{i<j} \lnot \left(x_i \land x_j\land \bigwedge_{k \notin \{i,j\}} \lnot x_k\right)\right) \lor \delta \\
\left(\bigwedge_{i<j} \left(\lnot x_i \lor \lnot x_j \lor \bigvee_{k \notin \{i,j\}} x_k\right)\right) \lor \delta \\
\bigwedge_{i<j} \left(\lnot x_i \lor \lnot x_j \lor \bigvee_{k \notin \{i,j\}} x_k \lor \delta\right) \\
(1 - x_i) + (1 - x_j) + \sum_{k \notin \{i,j\}} x_k + \delta \ge 1 \quad \text{for all $i<j$} \\
x_i + x_j - \sum_{k \notin \{i,j\}} x_k - 1 \le \delta \quad \text{for all $i<j$} \\
$$
Indeed, if $x_i=1$ and $x_j=1$ and all other $x_k=0$, then the LHS is $1$, which forces $1 \le \delta$ (hence $\delta=1$), as desired.

Comment: Thanks, Rob for your suggestion as always being helpful. I was seeing something like $atleast(k)_{i} x_{i}  \iff \bigwedge_{S \subset I | | S|=n-k+1} (\bigvee_{i \in S} x_{i})$ to translate logical $atleast$, but this is somewhat new to mine. Would you please, are there any materials, documentation, etc to learn logical form more deeply?

Comment: Rob, Would you please, I would like to add your suggestion as the 4th answer to the original question on OR.SE if you agree?

Comment: Here's a useful reference: R. Raman, I.E. Grossmann, Relation between MILP modelling and logical inference for chemical process synthesis, Computers & Chemical Engineering, Volume 15, Issue 2, 1991, Pages 73-84, ISSN 0098-1354, https://doi.org/10.1016/0098-1354(91)87007-V.

Comment: Rather than add a new answer, probably better to just link to this one.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. :)